# I can't compile a simple sample, `No rule to make target '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so`

Tags: opengl

The program is [this one](https://github.com/MauriceGit/Partikel_accelleration_on_GPU)

The instructions are pretty straightforward, `cmake .` and `make`

```
elect@elect-desktop:~/NetBeansProjects/Partikel_accelleration_on_GPU$ cmake .
-- Could NOT find Doxygen (missing:  DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE) 
-- Using X11 for window creation
-- Using GLX for context creation
CMake Warning at lib/glfw-3.1.1/CMakeLists.txt:403 (message):
  No glXGetProcAddressXXX variant found


-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/elect/NetBeansProjects/Partikel_accelleration_on_GPU
elect@elect-desktop:~/NetBeansProjects/Partikel_accelleration_on_GPU$ make
[ 22%] Built target glfw
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so', needed by 'bin/particleSim'.  Stop.
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:60: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/particleSim.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/particleSim.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:116: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

If I query the lib

```
elect@elect-desktop:~/NetBeansProjects/Partikel_accelleration_on_GPU$ dpkg-query -S /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so
libgl1-mesa-dev:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so
```

but it is already installed:

```
elect@elect-desktop:~/NetBeansProjects/Partikel_accelleration_on_GPU$ sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libgl1-mesa-dev is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

A `find` returns the following:

```
elect@elect-desktop:~/NetBeansProjects/Partikel_accelleration_on_GPU$ sudo find / -name libGL.so
/home/elect/Downloads/gl-graphics-compute-samples-linux-2.11/extensions/externals/lib/linux-arm32/libGL.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so
```

As far as I get, I should have something like `libGL.so.290.10` that should be the real lib, all the others shall be just links..

am I right?

What's the problem?

Ubuntu 15.10 x64, gtx 680

Edit:

```
elect@elect-desktop:~/NetBeansProjects/Partikel_accelleration_on_GPU$ ls -l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 ott  9 07:16 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so -> mesa/libGL.so


elect@elect-desktop:~/NetBeansProjects/Partikel_accelleration_on_GPU$ file -sL /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so: cannot open `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so' (No such file or directory)

elect@elect-desktop:~/NetBeansProjects/Partikel_accelleration_on_GPU$ readlink -f /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2.0
```

Tried to update the nvidia drivers, as soon as I terminate the window manager

`sudo service lightdm stop`

the system freezes and I have to hard reboot manually..

Tried with to boot in safe mode, I drop the root console, but the nvidia installation can't write to `/tmp` since I am root...

Ideas?

Edit:

```
elect@elect-desktop:~$ ls -l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2.0
ls: cannot access /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2.0: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Your post doesn't seem to mention *how* you are trying to compile it

Comment: Might you be on a 32-bit system perhaps?

Comment: No, paddingcomment

Comment: Did you check if it's maybe a broken link? either using `ls -l` or `file -sL /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so` or, ultimately, `readlink -f /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so`

Comment: Yep, it seems broken, doesn't?

Comment: Hmm... confusing - does it exist but is not readable, or does it not exist at all? `ls -l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2.0`

Comment: I'll try that this evening once I get home and let you know

Comment: Update, padding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

- booted in safe mode
- chose repair packages in order to make it mount filesystem in read/write automatically
- dropped root console
- `su elect` to login as me
- `cd Downloads` and `sudo bash .NVIDIA-driver`
- reboot
- it works as a charm